# Kafka Folder Creation Issue in Windows

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

I am working on triggering the Kafka server. I have ran the zookeeper server and kafka server commands in the command line situated in the root directory of Kafka.

When I run the `bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config\server.properties` command in the command line to trigger the Kafka server, I see that the corresponding Kafka files are created in the root folder (i.e. C:\kafka_2.12-2.3.1) of Kafka. However, I want these files to be created in the data >> kafka (i.e. C:\kafka_2.12-2.3.1\data\kafka) folder which I created.

All the tutorials I see are achieving this by just running the command above but in my machine, the command is creating a new folder in the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the `log.dirs` and `dataDir` of Kafka and Zookeeper to store their data in any directory to which they have access. The default for both is under `/tmp`, which doesn't exist on Windows, so you'll want to change it.

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007. I got confused between the different slash conventions followed in Linux and Windows and hence the issue.